Spring-Cloud-Stream serde SerializationException prevents messages from being published after it is already consumed and modified
I have my configuration like so:
spring:
  application:
    name: transaction-enricher-application
  integration:
    poller:
      fixed-delay: 5000
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: broker:9092 # Switch here to local instance when running on localhost
      bindings:
        enrichTransaction-in-0:
          consumer:
            batch-mode: true
            configuration:
              value:
                deserializer: com.example.demo.serdes.TransactionDeserializer
          destination: approvalRequest-out-0
        enrichTransaction-out-0:
          producer:
            useNativeEncoding: true
            configuration:
              value:
                serializer: com.example.demo.serdes.EnrichedTransactionSerializer

And here is my Service class which receives and publishes the message:
package com.example.demo.enricher;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import com.example.demo.service.EnrichmentService;
import java.util.function.Function;
import com.example.demo.domain.EnrichedTransaction;
import com.example.demo.domain.Transaction;

@Configuration
public class CashCardTransactionEnricher {

    @Bean
    EnrichmentService enrichmentService() {
        return new EnrichmentService();
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<Transaction, EnrichedTransaction> enrichTransaction(EnrichmentService enrichmentService) {
        return transaction -> {
            return enrichmentService.enrichTransaction(transaction);
        };
    }

}

And my serializer is like so:
package com.example.demo.serdes;

import com.example.demo.domain.EnrichedTransaction;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer;

public class EnrichedTransactionSerializer implements Serializer<EnrichedTransaction> {
    private JsonSerializer<EnrichedTransaction> jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer<>();

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, EnrichedTransaction data) {
        return jsonSerializer.serialize(topic, data);
    }
}

And my deserializer is like so:
package com.example.demo.serdes;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.example.demo.domain.Transaction;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer;

import java.util.Map;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.example.demo.domain.CashCard;

public class TransactionDeserializer implements Deserializer<Transaction> {

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {}

    @Override
    public Transaction deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
        if (data == null) {
            return null;
        }

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(data, Transaction.class);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            System.out.println("JsonProcessingException occured while deserializing Transaction" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error deserializing Transaction: " + e.getMessage());
            return new Transaction(0L, new CashCard(0L, "Error", 0.0));
        }

        return new Transaction(1L, new CashCard(1L, "Test Owner", 3.14)); // just to avoid any errors
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {}
}

And finally my enrichment service for approving the transaction is like so:
package com.example.demo.service;

import java.util.UUID;

import com.example.demo.domain.ApprovalStatus;
import com.example.demo.domain.CardHolderData;
import com.example.demo.domain.EnrichedTransaction;
import com.example.demo.domain.Transaction;

public class EnrichmentService {
    public EnrichedTransaction enrichTransaction(Transaction transaction) {
        return new EnrichedTransaction(
            transaction.id(),
            transaction.cashCard(),
            ApprovalStatus.APPROVED,
            new CardHolderData(
                UUID.randomUUID(),
                transaction.cashCard().owner(),
                "123 Main street"
            )
        );
    }
}

The error I am getting is like so:
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert value of class reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer specified in value.serializer

I really don't know what can be the root cause for that issue
I consume the message properly and receive it,
But when I publish it back after modifying it, I face that SerializationException
I have setup a repository here:
https://github.com/manonworldrepository/spring-cloud-stream-cashcard-application

./gradlew bootBuildImage
docker compose up -d --build
docker logs enricher

Then you will be able to see the exception
Your help is much appreciated

Hello the reason of failure was wrong ordering of binder properties, for more details you can check Spring documentation you have to review kafka.bindings & "common" bindings
here are required changes:
@Configuration
public class CashCardTransactionEnricher {

    @Bean
    EnrichmentService enrichmentService() {
        return new EnrichmentService();
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<Flux<List<Transaction>>, Flux<EnrichedTransaction>> enrichTransaction(EnrichmentService enrichmentService) {
        return transaction ->
                transaction.flatMap(Flux::fromIterable)
                        .map(enrichmentService::enrichTransaction);

    }

public class FluxSerializer implements Serializer<EnrichedTransaction> {

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, EnrichedTransaction data) {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(data);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
         //TODO log failure
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }
}

configurations:
spring:
  application:
    name: transaction-enricher-application
  integration:
    poller:
      fixed-delay: 5000
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost:9092 # Switch here to local instance when running on localhost
        bindings:
          enrichTransaction-in-0:
            consumer:
              configuration:
                value.deserializer: com.example.demo.serdes.TransactionDeserializer
          enrichTransaction-out-0:
            producer:
              configuration:
                key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
                value.serializer: com.example.demo.serdes.FluxSerializer
      bindings:
        enrichTransaction-in-0:
          binder: kafka
          group: enrich-consumer
          consumer:
            use-native-encoding: true
            batch-mode: true
          destination: approval-requests
        enrichTransaction-out-0:
          binder: kafka
          destination: enriched-transactions
          producer:
            use-native-encoding: true


spring:
  application:
    name: transaction-sink-application
  integration:
    poller:
      fixed-delay: 5000
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost:9092 # Switch here to local instance when running on localhost
      bindings:
        sinkToConsole-in-0:
          destination: enriched-transactions
          group: console-consumer
        cashCardTransactionFileSink-in-0:
          destination: enriched-transactions
          group: file-sink-consumer
    function:
      definition: sinkToConsole;cashCardTransactionFileSink


spring:
  application:
    name: transaction-source-application
  integration:
    poller:
      fixed-delay: 5000
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost:9092 # Switch here to local instance when running on localhost
      bindings:
        approvalRequest-out-0:
          destination: approval-requests
          binder: kafka


Your solution is just like my solution and both of them work with localhost:9092
But the issue comes with building a native image with docker containers as mentioned in the repository, but I was able to fix it by adding serdes to native image configuration like so:
https://github.com/manonworldrepository/spring-cloud-stream-cashcard-application/blob/master/cashcard-transaction-enricher/src/main/resources/META-INF/native-image/reflect-config.json because it was not detectable by native image and then it was not included in the image after building it and spring was still processing bytes.
